Prove that if $A=PJP^{-1}$ and $B^2=A$, then for some $J_1$ we have $B=PJ_1P^{-1}$ where $J_1^2=J$
Let $A=PJP^{-1}$ be a complex matrix where $J$ is a Jordan matrix, and there exists a $J_0$ with $J_0^2=J$. It is easy to show that $C=PJ_0P^{-1}$ satisfies $C^2=A$. My question is if, for every $B$ with $B^2=A$, then there exists a $J_1$ with $B=PJ_1P^{-1}$ where $J_1^2=J$.
I don't have anything else to add because I was given a matrix and was asked to find a square root using the trick above. I then asked myself if every square root is of that form, and I have no clue how to solve this.

You should tell the exact definition of these matrices. What field are they defined on? What's your definition of $\sqrt{J}$? Moreover, it is obvious that if B satisfies the condtition, so does -B.

With those assumptions, $J_1=P^{-1}BP$ so $J_1^2=\ldots$

Do you want $J_1$ to be a Jordan matrix?

The answer is yes. Since $B^2=A$ and $A=PJP^{-1}$, we have that $B^2=PJP^{-1}$. Multiplying this equation on the left by $P^{-1}$ and on the right by $P$, we obtain $P^{-1}B^2P=J$. Inserting $PP^{-1}=I$, we have $P^{-1}BPP^{-1}BP=J$. Define $J_1\equiv P^{-1}BP$. Then, the above equation reads $J_1^2=J$, as intended.
